# Facebook Network Audience - Optimisation in progress, ads are not showing

Tags: facebook, ads, mobile-ad-mediation

I have created a mediation group on admob with admob ads and Facebook Network Audience. However, the admob ads are showing, but for the Facebook Network Audience, it says "optimisation in progress". I do not know how to solve this problem, any help will be great. Thank you!